# iOS -- initWith methods under arc

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, automatic-ref-counting

In the old days, we were trained to write init methods like this:

Foo.h:

```
-(id) initWithInteger: (NSInteger) someNumber;
```

Foo.m:

```
-(id) initWithInteger: (NSInteger) someNumber {
    if ((self = [super init])) { 
       doSomeStuff;
    }
    return self;
 }
```

But those id casts are now no-nos.  So how should these methods now look?

EDIT: This is for a library.  So there is no telling what the calling code might look like.

Comment: What id cast? There's no type casts in your code.

Answer (score 8):

Why do you say returning `id` is a no-no? The [ARC specification](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html) says

> `init` methods must be instance methods and must return an Objective-C pointer type. Additionally, a program is ill-formed if it declares or contains a call to an init method whose return type is neither id nor a pointer to a super-class or sub-class of the declaring class (if the method was declared on a class) or the static receiver type of the call (if it was declared on a protocol).

Moreover, remember that using `ARC` is a per-file decision, i.e. the code compiled with ARC can be used with the code without ARC, and vice versa. In the case of the header file for a library, you should prepare it so that it can be used on both, but preparing it for non-ARC case should suffice.

Comment: In a library, you get an error that returning id is a fragile ABI.

Comment: @William Jockusch: Are you sure that's the precise error you're getting? The "fragile ABI" was the original Objective-C runtime. Returning id is not a runtime at all.

Comment: When I try to run the conversion tool, I get that error.  And possibly related: I can't find any way to tell it to not run the conversion tool on certain files.

Comment: @William Jockusch: To clarify: The *exact wording* of the error is "returning id is a fragile ABI"?

Comment: You're misunderstanding your error. The code is perfectly valid, assuming you're in an `NSObject` subclass.

Answer (score 4):

<strike>Here's what I do now:</strike>

```
-(id) initWithInteger: (NSInteger) someNumber {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) { 
       doSomeStuff;
    }
    return self;
}
```

It makes the warnings go away and it's logically equivalent, although not quite as elegant.

Duh, I feel like a fool now and didn't read the question to understand it. But I found this [link](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#family.semantics.init) that points to something that might help. Specifically it states, in Section 5:

> init methods must be instance methods and must return an Objective-C pointer type. Additionally, a program is ill-formed if it declares or contains a call to an init method whose return type is neither id nor a pointer to a super-class or sub-class of the declaring class (if the method was declared on a class) or the static receiver type of the call (if it was declared on a protocol).

Based on that, it looks like you don't have to do anything, which makes sense. Not even Apple is that cruel to its developers. Are you getting compiler errors? I haven't yet jumped to Lion so ARC is not on my radar yet.

Comment: Arc is what I'm concerned about here -- not the if (self) part.  My double parens also get rid of the warnings anyway.

Answer (score 0):

> In the old days, we were trained to write init methods like this:
>
> Foo.h:
>
> ```
> -(id) initWithInteger: (NSInteger) someNumber;
> ```
>
> Foo.m:
>
> ```
> -(id) initWithInteger: (NSInteger) someNumber {
>    if ((self = [super init])) { 
>       doSomeStuff;
>    }
>    return self;
> }
> ```
>
> But those id casts are now no-nos. So how should these methods now look?

Those aren't casts. In that context, that simply syntax declares the return type of the method, as the `(NSInteger)` part later on declares the type of that argument.

The syntax for declaring a method's return type has not changed under ARC. The code you showed would remain exactly the same.

Casts are expressions, so a cast of the sort prohibited by ARC can only occur in expression context. For example, if you said:

```
- (id) initWithCFThing:(CFThingRef)thing {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        _thing = (NSThing *)thing; //Casts expression of type CFThingRef to object pointer type NSThing *; this is invalid
    }
    return self;
 }
```

The cast in the assignment expression is invalid, because it casts from a CF object to an Objective-C object pointer (a “retainable object pointer”) with no bridge keyword. The inverse would likewise be invalid:

```
- (CFThingRef) CFThing {
    return _thing; //Implicitly casts expression of object pointer type NSThing *to type CFThingRef; this is invalid
}
```

Same problem in the other direction: The expression given to the `return` statement casts a retainable object pointer to a CF object type with no bridge keyword.

Note where the errors lie. In each case, the error is in an expression: in `initWithCFThing:`, it's the explicit cast-expression inside the assignment expression; in the accessor `CFThing`, it's the implicit cast of the expression inside the `return` statement to the method's return type.

In both cases, as in your case, the prototype of the method is completely valid. `(CFThingRef)` and `(id)` are still valid, with or without ARC, when you're declaring a return type or argument type for a method. Only as a cast expression is either syntax invalid, because the cast itself is invalid.

Adding a bridge keyword satisfies the compiler in a cast expression, because then you're telling it what you want it to do (bridge-crossing casts with no bridge keyword are invalid because the compiler would have to guess what you mean, and it refuses), but would be invalid in a type declaration because that is not ambiguous. The bridge crossing happens at the cast expression (when there is one), not at an argument passage or return.